# Failed to open Jython JAR file in Burp Suite in macOS Big Sur

Tags: python, macos-big-sur, burp

Failed to open Jython JAR file in Burp Suite, only getting this error for Python based Extensions, Java based ones are installing and loading ok.

Only change I did was installing iTerm2 and oh-my-zsh, may be this screwed up the path for python or Jython paths.

Error message -->

```
java.lang.Exception: Failed to open Jython JAR file
    at burp.h_1.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at burp.ah5.a(Unknown Source)
    at burp.evt.lambda$panelLoaded$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: Jython is an outdated technology which allows to execute Python2 code within a Java VM. I don't think it is installed on your system as individual software. May be it is required by Burp or some addon and you have to place a Jython JAR file in a special directory.

Comment: Thanks Robert, hard to get Jython installed into MacOS.. thanks for the tip..

Answer (score 2):

Needed jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar file and needs to select from Extender -> Options -> Python Environment and choose the downloaded file as Jython Standalone from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.2/jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

We always need to download the Jython Standalone file instead of Jython Installer.

Latest Jython Standalone file -
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.3/jython-standalone-2.7.3.jar